# 6 day trek in Nepal Himalaya

Tags: hiking, mountaineering, himalaya

What are some easy/moderate hikes in the Nepal Himalayas that do not span more than 6 days of walking? I looked at Jomsom trek but it is 8 days. I am looking for a trek that offers nice scenic beauty and good views of some 8000+ peaks. I also looked at everest base camp but that is a 21 day ordeal.
What options do I have here? I am not a climber, so difficulty level is w.r.t walking and fitness, not climbing :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is the trek to [Gosaikund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosaikunda) - also known as the "Frozen Lakes". [It can be done in six days walking.](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gabik/Travels/IndiaNepal/Gosaikund-Trek.html) However, I'm not sure I would call it easy- the first day, especially, will be very strenuous. However, it's a very pretty trek, and the first two days are very rewarding. Another advantage is that it's relatively close to Kathmandu, which means less traveling to get to the trail head.

Like the other popular treks in Nepal, it's a "tea house" trek - you don't need to cook or take a tent, which means you can travel light. When I was there (late 2006) many of the guesthouses were already equipped with solar showers, too.

The description I linked to above combines the trip to Gosaikund with a journey through Helambu - I didn't walk that part myself, so I can't vouch for it. I did do the walk through the [Langtang valley,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langtang) which is also relatively short (though longer than six days, as far as I can remember) and then crossed over to Gosaikund, and then walked down to Dunche (the walk down being done in a single, terrible, endless day).

I'm not sure there are any 8000 meter peaks nearby in this area, but Lantang Lirung is 7246 meters, which isn't too shabby. Perhaps because of this it's the least popular of the three most frequented trekking routes in Nepal (the other two being the [Everest Base Camp trek](http://wikitravel.org/en/Everest_Base_Camp_Trek) and around [Anapurna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapurna#Trekking)).

Answer (score 1):

Here are peaks on a route:

- Mera Peak (6654 m)
- Island Peak (6160 m)
- Pisang Peak (6091 m)
- Yala Peak (5500 m)
- Chulu East (6584 m)

Monsoon trek to Ghorepani poon hill 3210 mt is a five day trekking route from Kathmandu to Pokhara, Tikhedhunga, Ghorepani Poon Hill and then next morning climbing to Poon Hill where see the best panaromic views. It is the best view in the Himalayas. We see Dhaulagiri 8167 m, Mt Annapurna 8091 m, Mt Fish-tail alled holidy motion in Nepal. After 1987 it is not allowed to climb this peak, this holy mountain in Nepal. If any one tries to climb this mountain we will have many bad seasons in Nepal that means no rain.

It is a very popular trekking trail in the Himalayas. If you have time please visit one time. You never will forget a Poon Hill trek I am 100% sure.